# difference in data member initialisation in c++

Tags: c++, constructor

Just wondering,  **what is the difference between these initialization** in classes in C++

first:

```
Complex (): real(0), imaginary(0) { }
```

second:

```
Complex() {
   real = 0;
   imaginary = 0;
}
```

Comment: Difference is that second is not initialization but assignment

Comment: You know, other than the last dupe, which may be slightly harder to find, simply searching for the text you put in bold produces the other duplicates. This is a poor attempt at research before asking.

Comment: i didn't knew the terminolgy "member initialization list".
i thought it will be very hard to find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first variant members are directly *initialized* with values (use when can). This is the only way to initialize const members. Constness has many useful side effects.

In the second variant members are first *default-initialized* (by the compiler generated code) then *assigned* values (use when cannot avoid, usually can).

Comment: And the downvote is for...?

Comment: Not the down voter but I do know some people down vote answers on obvious dupes.

Comment: I guess the quality of this answer is not up there with those on the duplicates.